# Error en al insertar por comboBox anidados

Tags: php, combobox

Realizo un formulario de mantenimientos de equipos de computo, pero tengo un problema al insertar ya que mis campos final_id y nombre_id quiero dejarlos NULL (de la misma forma son NULL en mi BD) pero como los tengo en combobox anidados no me lo permite me marca error.

Notice: Undefined index: combo4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\reportes\action\addmantenimiento.php on line 21

Imprimo mi sentencia sql y me sale esto 
insert into mtto_equipos (tipo_id,modelo_id,mantenimiento_id, descripcion,final_id,nombre_id,created_at) value ("1","9","1","ddddddddd","0","", NOW())

Estructura BD Mantenimiento.

```
 id                Primaria int(11)
 tipo_id           Índice   int(11)
 modelo_id         Índice   int(11)
 mantenimiento_id  Índice   int(11)
 descripcion       varchar(250)
 final_id          Índice   int(11)
 nombre_id         Índice   int(11) 
 created_at
```

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 /*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
 if (empty($_POST['tipo_id'])) {
           $errors[] = "Tipo de Mantenimiento vacío";
        } 
  
   else if (
   !empty($_POST['tipo_id'])
   
  ){


  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

  $tipo_id = $_POST["tipo_id"];
  $modelo_id = $_POST["modelo_id"];
  $mantenimiento_id = $_POST["mantenimiento_id"];
  $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
  $final_id = $_POST["combo3"];
  $nombre_id = $_POST["combo4"];   
  $created_at="NOW()";


  // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql="insert into mtto_equipos (tipo_id,modelo_id,mantenimiento_id, descripcion,final_id,nombre_id,created_at) value (\"$tipo_id\",\"$modelo_id\",\"$mantenimiento_id\",\"$descripcion\",\"$final_id\",\"$nombre_id\", $created_at)";
         print_r($sql);
  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "El registro ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href="mantenimiento.php";
        </script>';
   
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times; </button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>

   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages))
   {
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
       
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) 
       {
         echo $message;
      
       }
         
       ?> 
       
      
    </div>
    <?php
   }
   
?>
```

datetime

ComboBox

```html
<?php
include("includes/config.inc.php");
include("includes/mysql.class.php");
$db = new MySQL();  
$db->open();
//$consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM priority WHERE id LIKE '$_POST[elegido]'");
$consulta = $db->consulta("select p.id, p.name  from nombre_maquina p, final c WHERE p.id = c.nombre_id
and c.id LIKE '$_POST[elegido]'");
if ($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta)) {
 do {
  echo 
  '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 }while($row = $db->fetch_array($consulta));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese no es un error es un `Notice`, solo te está avisando que la variable `$_POST["combo4"]` está indefinida.

Para el efecto que deseas puedes probar lo siguiente:

Cambiar:

```
$nombre_id = $_POST["combo4"];
```

por

```
$nombre_id = !empty($_POST["combo4"]) ? "'".$_POST["combo4"]."'" : "NULL";
```

y luego cambiar

```
insert into mtto_equipos (tipo_id,modelo_id,mantenimiento_id,
descripcion,final_id,nombre_id,created_at) value (\"$tipo_id\",\"$modelo_id\",\"$mantenimiento_id\",\"$descripcion\",\"$final_id\",\"$nombre_id\",
> $created_at)
```

por

```
insert into mtto_equipos (tipo_id,modelo_id,mantenimiento_id,
descripcion,final_id,nombre_id,created_at) value (\"$tipo_id\",\"$modelo_id\",\"$mantenimiento_id\",\"$descripcion\",\"$final_id\",$nombre_id, > $created_at)
```

Esto hará que la Query llegue con comillas a MySQL solo si existe un valor para nombre_id, mientras que llegará como `NULL` sin comillas si no existe dicho valor.

---

**Importante**: Trata de usar la librería `PDO` para las consultas MySQL con PHP, tu código es muy susceptible a ataques informáticos, como por ejemplo SQL Injection.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias @Sebastian Araya.